# Adding AWS account to Trend Micro Deep Security Manager

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, deepsecurity

Below Lambda script is supposed to add AWS account to Trend Micro DSM (which is also in an AWS account). Endpoints are set up between the accounts allowing communication. It's failing with 400, it cannot add the account:

**Logs:**

2020-11-06T13:28:37.612+00:00   START RequestId: 074eff37-00cc-480b-affb-2e28f0e2a8af Version: $LATEST

2020-11-06T13:28:42.034+00:00   Assuming role: arn:aws:iam::414025531860:role/pcs-pipeline-role

2020-11-06T13:28:42.575+00:00   Assumed successfully!

2020-11-06T13:28:42.575+00:00   /var/runtime/botocore/vendored/requests/api.py:72: DeprecationWarning: You are using the get() function from 'botocore.vendored.requests'. This dependency was removed from Botocore and will be removed from Lambda after 2021/01/30. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/removing-the-vendored-version-of-requests-from-botocore/. Install the requests package, 'import requests' directly, and use the requests.get() function instead.

2020-11-06T13:28:42.575+00:00   DeprecationWarning

2020-11-06T13:28:44.927+00:00   Allowing public IP for executing Lambda, 34.247.33.230/32, to temporarily call Trend DSM

2020-11-06T13:28:45.070+00:00   DONE!

2020-11-06T13:28:50.076+00:00   Logging into Trend DSM as Org tenant

2020-11-06T13:28:50.076+00:00   /var/runtime/botocore/vendored/requests/api.py:72: DeprecationWarning: You are using the post() function from 'botocore.vendored.requests'. This dependency was removed from Botocore and will be removed from Lambda after 2021/01/30. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/removing-the-vendored-version-of-requests-from-botocore/. Install the requests package, 'import requests' directly, and use the requests.post() function instead.

2020-11-06T13:28:50.076+00:00   DeprecationWarning

2020-11-06T13:28:50.233+00:00   /var/runtime/urllib3/connectionpool.py:988: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'gdc-pcs-tre-dsmelb-fbsp95snsrjw-2115947587.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings

2020-11-06T13:28:50.233+00:00   InsecureRequestWarning,

2020-11-06T13:28:50.319+00:00   200

2020-11-06T13:28:50.319+00:00   Logged in!

2020-11-06T13:28:50.319+00:00   Getting cloud accounts for Trend org tenant...

2020-11-06T13:28:50.319+00:00   /var/runtime/botocore/vendored/requests/api.py:72: DeprecationWarning: You are using the get() function from 'botocore.vendored.requests'. This dependency was removed from Botocore and will be removed from Lambda after 2021/01/30. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/removing-the-vendored-version-of-requests-from-botocore/. Install the requests package, 'import requests' directly, and use the requests.get() function instead.

2020-11-06T13:28:50.319+00:00   DeprecationWarning

2020-11-06T13:28:50.493+00:00   /var/runtime/urllib3/connectionpool.py:988: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'xyz-abc-tre-dsmelb-fbsp95snsrjw-7443282981.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings

2020-11-06T13:28:50.493+00:00   InsecureRequestWarning,

2020-11-06T13:28:50.528+00:00   Retrieved!

2020-11-06T13:28:50.528+00:00   Checking if tenant account already in Trend DSM Org Tenant

2020-11-06T13:28:50.528+00:00   Not found

2020-11-06T13:28:50.528+00:00   Adding 11994547362545 as Trend cloud account...

2020-11-06T13:28:50.528+00:00   /var/runtime/botocore/vendored/requests/api.py:72: DeprecationWarning: You are using the post() function from 'botocore.vendored.requests'. This dependency was removed from Botocore and will be removed from Lambda after 2021/01/30. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/removing-the-vendored-version-of-requests-from-botocore/. Install the requests package, 'import requests' directly, and use the requests.post() function instead.

2020-11-06T13:28:50.528+00:00   DeprecationWarning

2020-11-06T13:28:50.693+00:00   /var/runtime/urllib3/connectionpool.py:988: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'xyz-abc-tre-dsmelb-fbsp95snsrjw-7443282981.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings

2020-11-06T13:28:50.693+00:00   InsecureRequestWarning,

2020-11-06T13:28:51.373+00:00   400

2020-11-06T13:28:51.373+00:00   Failed!

```
`No lines are selected.
import os
import json
import time
import boto3
from botocore.vendored import requests
import layer as utils
def handler(event, context):
    try:
        # Extract the Job ID
        job_id = event['CodePipeline.job']['id']
        event_data = utils.parse_event_data(event)
        print(event_data)
        trend_micro_deep_security_integration(event_data['TenantAccountId'], event_data['Organisation'])
        utils.put_job_success(job_id)
    except Exception as err:
        utils.put_job_failure(job_id, str(err))
def trend_micro_deep_security_integration(tenant_account_id, tenant_organisation):
    #retrieve trend tenant password from ssm param store
    client = boto3.client('ssm', region_name='eu-west-1')    
    TREND_TENANT_PASSWORD = client.get_parameter(Name='TrendTenantPassword', WithDecryption=True)['Parameter']['Value']
    #assume role in aws provider account for trend dsm
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
    trend_account_role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::654533721364:role/{}'.format(os.environ['DEPLOY_ROLE'])
    TREND_SESSION = utils.get_sts_session(sts_client, trend_account_role_arn)
    #determine public ip of executing lambda function
    public_ip = requests.get('https://checkip.amazonaws.com').text.rstrip()    
    global LAMBDA_PUBLIC_IP
    LAMBDA_PUBLIC_IP = '{}/32'.format(public_ip)
    #add lambda public ip as temp ingress cidr ip
    SG_ID = 'sg-01ct911f8ch7d2ed5'
    changed = authorize_trend_elb_ingress(TREND_SESSION, SG_ID)
    if changed:
        time.sleep(5)
    org_name = tenant_organisation.upper().strip()
    #log into trend dsm
    payload = get_trend_auth_payload_json(org_name, TREND_TENANT_PASSWORD)
    cookie = get_trend_org_cookie(org_name, payload)
    # check and if required, add tenant account into their trend tenant for the assigned org
    dsm_account_names = get_trend_org_cloud_accounts(cookie)
    if not is_account_in_trend_dsm(dsm_account_names, tenant_account_id):
        success = add_trend_cloud_account(cookie, tenant_account_id)
    else:
        success = True
    # always remove temp ingress rule
    revoke_trend_elb_ingress(TREND_SESSION, SG_ID)
    #if any error when adding account, throw exception
    if not success:
        raise Exception("Failed to add tenant as cloud account in Trend Deep Security Manager!")
    print("Trend Micro Deep Security Manager integration complete!")
    
## TREND DEEP SECURITY HELPER FUNCTIONS ###
def trend_sg_ingress_rule_exists(sg_rules):
    for elem in sg_rules:
        matches = [ x for x in elem['IpRanges'] if x['CidrIp'] == LAMBDA_PUBLIC_IP ]
        if any(matches):
            return True
    return False
def authorize_trend_elb_ingress(TREND_SESSION, SECURITY_GROUP_ID):
    ec2 = TREND_SESSION.resource('ec2', region_name='eu-west-1')
    elb_security_group = ec2.SecurityGroup(SECURITY_GROUP_ID)
    if trend_sg_ingress_rule_exists(elb_security_group.ip_permissions):
        return False
    print("Allowing public IP for executing Lambda, {}, to temporarily call Trend DSM".format(LAMBDA_PUBLIC_IP))
    elb_security_group.authorize_ingress(
        CidrIp=LAMBDA_PUBLIC_IP,
        FromPort=777,
        ToPort=777,
        IpProtocol='tcp',
    )
    print("DONE!")
    return True
def revoke_trend_elb_ingress(TREND_SESSION, SECURITY_GROUP_ID):
    ec2 = TREND_SESSION.resource('ec2', region_name='eu-west-1')
    elb_security_group = ec2.SecurityGroup(SECURITY_GROUP_ID)
    if not trend_sg_ingress_rule_exists(elb_security_group.ip_permissions):
        return False
    print("Revoking public IP for executing Lambda, {}, from Trend DSM ELB SG".format(LAMBDA_PUBLIC_IP))
    elb_security_group.revoke_ingress(
        CidrIp=LAMBDA_PUBLIC_IP,
        FromPort=777,
        ToPort=777,
        IpProtocol='tcp',
    )
    print("DONE!")
def is_account_in_trend_dsm(dsm_names, account_id):
    print("Checking if tenant account already in Trend DSM Org Tenant")
    for dsm_account_name in dsm_names:
        if account_id == dsm_account_name[-12:]:
            print("Found!")
            return True
    
    print("Not found")
    return False    
def get_trend_org_cookie(org_name, payload):
    print("Logging into Trend DSM as Org tenant")
    headers = {'content-type': "application/json", 'accept': "application/json"  }
    r = requests.post(
        url = "https://xyz-abc-tre-dsmelb-fbsp95snsrjw-2912957566.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/rest/authentication/login",
        headers= headers,
        data = payload,
        verify=False
    )
    print(r.status_code)
    print("Logged in!")
    return r.text
def get_trend_auth_payload_json(org_name, org_tenant_password):
   auth = {
       'dsCredentials' : { 'userName' : 'MasterAdmin' , 'password' : org_tenant_password, 'tenantName' : org_name}
   }
   return json.dumps(auth)
def get_trend_org_cloud_accounts(cookie_string):
    cookie = {'sID': cookie_string}
    headers = {'content-type': "application/json", 'accept': "application/json"  }
    print("Getting cloud accounts for Trend org tenant...")
    r = requests.get(
        url = "https://xyz-abc-tre-dsmelb-fbsh952n1rbw-2185847414.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/rest/cloudaccounts/",
        headers= headers,
        cookies=cookie,
        verify=False
    )
    resp = r.json()['ListCloudAccountsResponse']
    print("Retrieved!")
    return [ x['name'] for x in resp['cloudAccount'] ]
def add_trend_cloud_account(cookie_string, account_id):
    cookie = {'sID': cookie_string}
    headers = {'content-type': "application/json", 'accept': "application/json"  }
    info = {}
    info['AddAwsAccountRequest'] = {}
    info['AddAwsAccountRequest']['crossAccountRole'] = {}
    info['AddAwsAccountRequest']['crossAccountRole']['roleArn'] = 'arn:aws:iam::{}:role/gdc-pcs-trend-micro-dsm-role'.format(account_id)
    info['AddAwsAccountRequest']['crossAccountRole']['externalId'] = '7F4DC12D-53B2-1BEX-7CB7-8759CDADEB71'
    print('Adding {} as Trend cloud account...'.format(account_id))
    r = requests.post(
        url = "https//xyz-abc-tre-dsmelb-fbsp95snsrjw-7443282981.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/rest/cloudaccounts/aws",
        headers= headers,
        cookies=cookie,
        data = json.dumps(info),
        verify=False
    )
    print(r.status_code)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print("Done!")
        return True
    else:
        print("Failed!")
        return False`
```

Comment: Please isolate the error further. It would be helpful, if you could at least isolate the function during which the request and the error response occur. You should also isolate the output in the log files to only the output occuring in that function.

Comment: I though the log information points that out. The account search was successful (Not found) but adding the account to the DSM not. So the last function is failing. AWS role seems to be ok.

Comment: The `400` status code means `Bad Request`, so there is some issue with the request that means it cannot be completed. If you log the actual message in the response body, that should shed some light on this.